# Special Characters on oracle DB SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Currently we are using this code to identify several rows which contain special characters. But it seems it's not capturing some events. Could you please share the optimized script to use for this scenario.

```
regexp_like(column_name, '^[^a-zA-Z]*$') then 'number'
regexp_like(column_name, '^[^g-zG-Z]*$') then 'hex'
```

Answer (score 0):

If the string can have multiple characters, then you need to take this into account:

```
regexp_like(column_name, '^[0-9]+$') as is_integer
regexp_like(column_name, '^[0-9A-Fa-f]+$') as is_hex
```

Of course, both of these could be true.

Comment: hi Thanks for you response want to find string like 'F@C(!!'

Comment: @Cmadu . . . Then I would expect you to ask a *new* question.  That pattern seems to have nothing to do with this question.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the shorter versions:

```
regexp_like(column_name, '^\d+$') as is_integer
regexp_like(column_name, '^[[:xdigit:]]+$') as is_hex
```

Comment: hi Thanks for you response want to find string like 'F@C(!!'

Comment: You did not mention this in your question. Please elaborate your question accordingly.

Comment: Sorry for thatCurrently we are using this code to identify several rows which contain special characters. But it seems it's not capturing some events. Could you please share the optimized script to use for this scenario

Comment: Sorry for that Currently we are using this code to identify several rows which contain only SPECIAL CHARACTERs 'F@C(!!'. But it seems it's not capturing some SPECIAL CHARACTER. script should capture only special characters. Could you please share the optimized script to use for this scenario case
           when regexp_like(column_name '^[^a-zA-Z]*$') then 'number'
           when regexp_like(column_name, '^[^g-zG-Z]*$') then 'hex'
           else 'string'
end

Comment: Please ask a *new* question for that, specify clearly your requirements.